# ¿Cómo ejecutar un archivo php sin virtual host usando xampp?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

Por cuestiones de trabajo configure el archivo *C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf* y agregue algunos Virtual Host pero antes de realizar esto estaba tomando un curso de php y lo que hacía en mi navegador era escribir lo siguente *localhost/curso_php/archivo.php* y podía ejecutar mis archivos pero ahora ya no puedo hacerlo.
Entonces mi pregunta es ¿Cómo ejecutar los archivos php de mi curso que no están configurados como virtual host? ¿Puedo ejecutar proyectos con Virtual host y sin Virtual host al mismo tiempo?

Answer (score 0):

Al configurar los virtual host deberías agregar tus proyectos a uno de ellos, dentro de unos de los virtualhost que tengas accesibles crea un directorio por cada proyecto y podrás acceder a ellos.
Incluso podrías crear un host virtual especifico para alojar dichos proyectos

```
localhost/hostvirtual/pryecto1/index.php
localhost/hostvirtual/pryecto2/index.php
```

Comment: ¿Cree usted que pueda ejecutar archivos php de mi curso sin configurar como Virtual Host?